# Makeindex fails when called from a script

Tags: xetex, glossaries

I've written a (python) script to automate my XeLaTeX run. What it does:

- creates a temp dir
- copies necessary tex, bib and image files into it from the cwd
- runs `xelatex` on the tex file
- runs `biber` on the file basename
- runs `makeglossaries` on the file basename
- runs `xelatex` x 2  on the tex file
- copies the resulting PDF back to current working dir

So far, so straightforward; I'm just emulating what I would do manually. However, my `makeglossaries` call fails with the following error:

```
makeglossaries version 2.02 (2011-04-02)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
makeindex  -s "test-mmd3.ist" -t "/var/folders/In/Inv5nKauESSVg9ibb4l3c++++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG330ND/test-mmd3.glg" -o "/var/folders/In/Inv5nKauESSVg9ibb4l3c++++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG330ND/test-mmd3.gls" "/var/folders/In/Inv5nKauESSVg9ibb4l3c++++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG330ND/test-mmd3.glo"
Index style file test-mmd3.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

***Call to makeindex failed***

Possible cause of problem:

Style name indicates makeindex, but may be in xindy format.
Remember to use \setStyleFile to specify the name
of the style file rather than redefining \istfilename
explicitly.

Check '/var/folders/In/Inv5nKauESSVg9ibb4l3c++++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG330ND/test-mmd3.glg' for details
```

I've checked that all the necessary files are being produced (in particular, the `.ist` file), `openout_any` is set to `a`, and the run completes fine when I do it manually using the same steps. I'm wondering if the error has anything to do with the the `-s test-mmd3.ist` option in `makeindex`; should it be using the full path, i.e. `/var/folders/In/Inv5nKauESSVg9ibb4l3c++++TI/-Tmp-/tmpG330ND/test-mmd3.ist`?

Comment: @urschrei: in which directory are you  when running makeindex? In the doc dir or temp dir? And is the style file also copied into the temp dir?

Comment: In the temp dir, and yes, the style file is definitely there.

Comment: rename the style file to `test-mmd3.mst` instead of `.ist`. Then run `makeindex` _without_ specifieing a style file with the `-s` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over how it's called, since makeglossaries calls makeindex. I could just run Makeindex manually and skip makeglossaries (I'll never be using Xindy anyway), I suppose.

Comment: ok, then put the style file `test-mmd3.ist` into your home directory `texmf/makeindex/` if it doesn't exist, create it. Then it should be found by `makeindex`

Comment: I doubt that you are in the temp directory when calling makeglossaries. A simple `makeglossaries file` doesn't show absolute pathes. Also I get exactly the same error/messages as you when I start makeglossaries from another directory with an absolute path as argument. I also get errors when I call makeglossaries from the document folder but still with an absolute path as argument but then the error message is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Originally posted as a comment by Ulrike Fischer)

I doubt that you are in the temp directory when calling makeglossaries. A simple `makeglossaries file` doesn't show absolute paths. Also I get exactly the same error/messages as you when I start makeglossaries from another directory with an absolute path as argument. I also get errors when I call makeglossaries from the document folder but still with an absolute path as argument but then the error message is slightly different.

Comment: Xindy also has the same problem, we must copy the tex file to xindy's Temp folders, then xindy can work.

Answer (score 1):

For glossaries when it doesn't use Xindy, we have to use makeglossaries test.tex in the folder where test.tex is.
Xindy also has the similar path problem, but we must copy the tex file to xindy's Temp folders, then xindy just can work.

I use

```
xindy --interactive -L....
```

to find the temp folder of the xindy, then I copy the test.tex in it, it looks like:

```
/private/var/folders/9u/3d3edDd34trdetrgdDEffg/
```

Then I use

```
xelatex test.tex, makeglossaries test, xelatex test.tex
```

there, It works.

But it is so dirty, I don't know how to resolve it fine.